# Angular UI Router Not Animating States?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Having a major issue with Angular 1.3.15 and UI Router 0.2.15, they aren't animating my state changes or anything. I am not sure what is going on. I simplified my CSS to just animate in and out but it doesn't even seem to apply the `ng-scope` class to the element. I can't recreate it because it seems to work on every plunkr I try but on mine it is not applying these methods or anything.

Here is the image of my DOM not having the classes.

[image]

And I'm also trying to think what else could be the issue. Angular, and Angular Animate are on the same version, the modules are being injected. I'm changing states just fine, but the animations are not working what so ever. If anyone else has come across a fix for this let me know, here is the plunkr I was testing everything out on.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WV1JksXCBRl7wG6p00ZS?p=preview

Here is my CSS, super basic and dry.

```
.view {
    position: relative;
}

.view.ng-enter {
    opacity: 1;
}

.view.ng-leave {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Just a side note, the `data-` attribute comes from my gulp plugin and I am using Javascript templates for basically everything but the `index.html`. Anything helps!

Edit:
Here is a GIF of what is happening when the route changes
https://gyazo.com/e82d58fa12f30eb93bc9dbd33a5fce9d

Comment: The strangest fix happened, it is definitely broken in Angular 1.4.* but I just reinstalled Angular about 4 or 5 times and restarted my server and it started doing the `ng-scope` but as for the animations, that took more work. I started beginning to mess with the `ng-*` classes and randomly it started working. Fix being an ng-animate class needs `transition: 0.4s all` and then your custom pieces below it. I was not aware and was using SCSS to animate pieces `animate.scss`, this does not work. It needs the transition property.